# Why is facial symmetry of the opposite sex attractive?

Tags: evolution, symmetry

Why do we give so much importance to the symmetry of face in the opposite sex? Why do we yearn to reproduce with a person with a beautiful face? How is it important for survival, if at all? Is there a biological explanation for this?

Comment: Who exactly is "we" here?  From my own experience & observation, I hardly think it is universal to regard the face as all that important in attractiveness.

Comment: Well it does seem like symmetric faces are more attractive (to both genders; [Grammar and Thornil, 1994](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1994-45035-001))

Comment: @Remi.b: I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say.  I'll accept that symmetric faces are more attractive than non-symmetric ones; what I'm questioning is the idea that the face, whether beautiful or not, is more than a minor factor in overall attractiveness.

Comment: @jamesqf What does it matter if its minor or major factor? My question was about the fact that it clearly has some importance in survival why else would people care about facial symmetry?

Comment: @user10093863: The problem is your assumption that "we yearn to reproduce with a person with a beautiful face", which at least from my observation isn't generally true.  I could cite any number of examples, from the feminist complaints about men not looking at their faces, to the cruel description of a fat woman as "but she has such a pretty face".

Comment: @jamesqf You clearly are living in a dreamworld or have never been to a normal school or college, let alone an outdoor setting like restaurant or a bar. If you genuinely believe that people don't give any importance to facial symmetry in the opposite sex, then I think you are living in the world of non-smelly farts and invisible poops.

Comment: @user10093863: At the risk of descending into crudity, are you living in a dreamworld where you've never heard the expression "just put a bag over her head"?  Do a thought experiment (or a real one if you can get funding :-)).  Take your bar or whatever, dress half the people in revealing clothing but have them wear masks, have the other half show their faces but wear something that completely conceals the body.  Now which half do you suppose is going to get the most interest from the opposite sex?

Comment: @jamesqf Wow that makes no sense. My question is regarding facial symmetry, it has nothing to do with the body.

Comment: @user10093863: No, you asked explicitly why "...we yearn to reproduce with a person with a beautiful face?"  The answer to that is that WE don't.  Now maybe some people do, because different people find different things attractive.  But if beautiful faces were a major factor in sexual attraction, Playboy could have been a success with nothing but head shots :-)

Comment: @jamesqf The reason you won't admit to the fact that you and I and everyone else is highly attracted to facial symmetry is because you want to live in a world where we are attracted based on important things like someone's intelligence rather than their looks, however, I hate to break this bubble for you but humans are still pretty primitive when it comes to attraction. Our brains have not evolved much for thousands of years and we used to be attracted to others based on their facial symmetry and physicality. So, what makes you think that it is any different nowadays?

Comment: @user10093863: You've entirely misunderstood what I've been trying to point out, which has nothing to do with whether I'd like intelligence to be sexually attractive.  (I don't think I've even mentioned intelligence AT ALL.)  It's that when it comes to sexual attraction, the face plays little part, at least for men.  (I think also for women, but I have limited data, not being one.)  To be crude (since nothing else seems to get through), most men look at tits, ass, legs, waist &c long before the face, and will pretty much ignore the face if the rest is attractive enough.

Comment: @jamesqf As I have mentioned before, you live in a dreamland. Producers hire pretty faces for lead roles because they know that more people are going to watch. Why do you think people want to watch pretty faces? Because it is soothing to the eye? No, because people are more attracted to pretty faces and find it hard not to look at them. What do you think this phenomenon is if not sexual attraction? Ever heard of the phrase 'sex sells'? If it was merely about 'tits, ass, legs, waist, etc' then wouldn't they hire based on physique rather than facial symmetry? Its so hard to get through you.

Comment: @user10093863: The first problem with your reasoning is that anyone movie/TV producers hire (for other than character rolls) is already several standard deviations out on the T&A bell curve.  You don't see them hiring the fat girls (or men) with pretty faces, do you?  The second problem is assuming that movies (other than porn, of course) are all about sexual attraction.  While I'm not a movie fan, people do seem to watch them for reasons other than sex. And if it seems hard to get through to me, it's because you insist on holding to an obviously false thesis :-)

Comment: Are you claiming that face symmetry is unimportant for gay people?

Comment: @swbarnes2 Are you virtue signalling here?

Comment: Why is it 'virtue' signaling' to acknowledge the existence of gay people?

Comment: Because biology.

Answer (score 1):

Facial symmetry is currently [believed](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1090513801000836) the be a sign of developmental stability and good health and thus good genes.  More precisely a sign of [genetic diversity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1090513804000789) in a potential partner.

Answer (score 0):

Parasites, disease, or injury can cause asymmetries. The complexity of the face, and our visual sensitivity to facial features, makes us most sensitive to subtle symmetries and asymmetries in facial features.

Therefore facial symmetry is a sensitive and reliable indicator of health. Healthy mates are more likely to possess good genes to pass on for strong healthy offspring. Healthy mates are also likely to be more physically capable of producing and raising offspring.

Any individual who possesses a gene that causes attraction to symmetric partners is more likely to select such a mate. That individual is therefore likely to produce more offspring, and more likely to produce strong healthy offspring.

Therefore the gene for attraction to facial symmetry is more likely to survive and spread.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Your answer sounds reasonable, however, it is likely to receive a more favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice [Answer] effectively on this site and then edit your answer accordingly. Thanks! 